# How to remove first few objects from NSMutableArray

Tags: uitableview, nsmutablearray

I have a `NSmutableArray` like this.

[obj1,obj2,obj3,obj5,......];

this has assigned into a `UITableView`

lets say user clicked on the 3rd cell. then I need to create another `NSMutableArray` like this.

[obj3,obj4,obj5,------]; need to remove first few objects from the array upto the current object. How can I do this.
please help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this...for remove specific object from any mutable array...

```
[array removeObjectAtIndex:0];
```